# How do I solve this strange DropShadow issue in UWP Composition?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm getting undesirable effects when using a drop shadow in composition. To replicate this problem, follow these steps:

**Step 1**: create a new UWP project and target *Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)*

**Step 2**: copy the following into `MainPage.xaml`

```
<Page x:Class="App1.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="_shadow" Width="500" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

        <Canvas x:Name="_shadowSource" Width="500" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="DarkOrange" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Aquamarine" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Crimson" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="BlueViolet" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="DarkGreen" Canvas.Top="250" Canvas.Left="250"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Gold" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="300"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="MediumAquamarine" Canvas.Top="350" Canvas.Left="350"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Violet" Canvas.Top="400" Canvas.Left="400"/>
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="LightSeaGreen" Canvas.Top="450" Canvas.Left="450"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Step 3**: copy the following into `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Numerics;
using Windows.UI.Composition;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
            var shadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
            var layer = compositor.CreateLayerVisual();

            shadow.SourcePolicy = CompositionDropShadowSourcePolicy.InheritFromVisualContent;

            layer.Shadow = shadow;
            layer.Size = new Vector2(500, 500);

            var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(_shadowSource);

            layer.Children.InsertAtBottom(visual);

            ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(_shadow, layer);
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of `_shadowSource` is moved to a new layer with a shadow set as `InheritFromVisualContent`. When the app loads, you'll see the shadows render fine, but resizing the app creates visual glitches.

[image: Shadow glitch]

Here's what happens when you comment out the line `//layer.Shadow = shadow;`

[image: No shadow]

What's happening here? Why does a shadow cause this?

Comment: FWIW, I have the same kind of issue (smells like a bug to me), posted on github here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

When your window height is less than 500, the `_shadowSource` height is still 500 because you have `Width="500" Height="500"` in your XAML. So it’s clipped and only upper portion is visible.

But you add your shadow to another element named `_shadow`. This one doesn’t have fixed size, so it resizes to the size of your window, i.e. no clipping happens. That’s why your circles get distorted to ellipses, and you see these nasty artifacts in the lower portion of your window — if your shadow would be laid out correctly, these parts of the layer would be clipped away and invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still doesn't make a difference. I'm only using `_shadow` as a visual container. I updated it to have the same properties, but the squashing effect is still present.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [DropShadowPanel](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/DropShadowPanel/DropShadowPanel.cs) control of [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) to apply drop shadow for the Ellipse. It worked well.

You could try the following:

```xml
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:control="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    ...
>    

<Canvas  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="DarkOrange" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Aquamarine" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Crimson" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="BlueViolet" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="250" Canvas.Left="250"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="DarkGreen" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="300"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Gold" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="350" Canvas.Left="350"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="MediumAquamarine" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="400" Canvas.Left="400"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Violet" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
        <control:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" Canvas.Top="450" Canvas.Left="450"
                      ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                      OffsetX="5.0"
                      OffsetY="5.0"
                      Color="Black">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="LightSeaGreen" />
        </control:DropShadowPanel>
</Canvas>
```

I check its source code, I found that it will update shadow size and other things when the app window is resized. So, maybe, it's the key point. You could 
refer to its [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/DropShadowPanel/DropShadowPanel.cs#L104) to extend your own code. Or you could directly use the `DropShadowPanel` control.

Comment: Thanks, but these ellipses are a reduced example of something more complex and I don't have the ability to micro-manage the shadows per element. The purpose is to use the `InheritFromVisualContent` policy to produce a unified mask for the shadow effect. It's best to pretend you don't know the content of `_shadowSource`.